drizzle-kit not using .env.test or .env.development in bun.js
I'm working with bun.js and I'm trying to do bun run drizzle-kit push, bun run drizzle-kit generate, bun run drizzle-kit migrate but no any of these commands works for testing environment, the drizzle cannot get my DATABASE_URL from .env.test or .env.development or .env.local...etc I discovered that drizzle-kit can get the environment variables only from .env.
This is my drizzle.config.ts file:
import { defineConfig } from "drizzle-kit";
import config from "config";

export default defineConfig({
  out: "./drizzle",
  schema: "./src/db/schema.ts",
  dialect: "postgresql",
  dbCredentials: {
    url: process.env.DATABASE_URL as string,
  },
});

I'm trying to generate migrations for my DATABASE_URL in .env.test but its always getting the URL from .env only, and if I don't have .env file it will give me error says:
Error  Either connection "url" or "host", "database" are required for PostgreSQL database connection

Is there any way to use different .env file for drizzle?
Note: I am using built in bun.js .env, I am not using any additional dotenv packages

I ended up using --env-file flag to tell bun what .env file to use when I'm running the drizzle commands, for example:
bun run --env-file=.env.test drizzle-kit push

And I created a scripts in package.json specifically for those operations like bellow:-
"scripts": {
    "start": "bun run server.ts",
    "dev": "bun run --watch server.ts",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test bun test --preload ./tests/setup.ts",// this is a bonus line. this line will make sure the tests will use .env.test when test is running and we load a global setup file before starting the tests
    "test-drizzle-generate": "bun --env-file=.env.test drizzle-kit generate",
    "test-drizzle-migrate": "bun --env-file=.env.test drizzle-kit migrate",
    "test-drizzle-push": "bun --env-file=.env.test drizzle-kit push"
  }


Option 1: Manually load the .env.test file inside your drizzle.config.ts using dotenv.config({ path: '.env.test' }).
Option 2: Use dotenv-cli to load environment variables from .env.test and run your commands.

Thank you, but I dont use dotenv packages, bun has built in dotenv handling without any extra packages

Your answer need many improvments, its need to be clear and covers all the code aspects and also related to the quesion specifically. please follow the good answer guide here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
